# When I make a bookmark and click on it the hidden value changes once and every time I add a new bookmark

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I click on the bookmark head it will change 'hidden' to false but it won't take off the 'hidden' class. Also when I click the bookmark head more than once it runs more than what's needed in the console.log.

It is worth noting as well that when another bookmark is added the rating from the first bookmark is added also, it repeats this to every new bookmark added.

What it is supposed to do is make a bookmark that can be clicked. Once clicked a drop down menu is supposed to appear that has the Description and Url. Then when I click the bookmark head again it should close.

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
import cuid from 'cuid'

let items = []


function bookmarkTemplate(item) {


    let itemTitle = `<li data-item-id="${item.id}" class="bookmark-drop-downs">${item.title}, Rating: ${item.rating}</li>

        <ul class='hidden'>
            <li>${item.url}</li>
            <li>${item.desc}</li>
        </ul>
`

    if (!item.hidden) {
        itemTitle = `<li id='${item.id}'>${item.title}, Rating: ${item.rating}</li>

        <ul>
            <li>${item.url}</li>
            <li>${item.desc}</li>
        </ul>
        `
    }

    return itemTitle


}

function dropDownForm() {
    return `
    <form id = 'bookmark-form' >

    <label for='title'>Title</label>
    <input id="title" name='bookmark-form' type="text" required>
    <label for='url'>Url</label>
    <input id="url" name='bookmark-form' type="url" required>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name='bookmark-form'></textarea>
    <label for='rate'>Rate</label>
    <select id='rate' name='bookmark-form' type="text">
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Star</option>
        <option value="3">3 Star</option>
        <option value="4">4 Star</option>
        <option value="5">5 Star</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    <button type="reset">Cancel</button>

</form>`

}


function createItem(title, desc, rating) {

    return {
        id: cuid(),
        title,

        hidden: true,
        desc,
        rating
    }

}

function handleAddItem() {

    console.log('addItem called')

    $('body').on('submit', '#bookmark-form', e => {

        e.preventDefault()

        let titleValue = $('#title').val()
        let description = $('#description').val()
        let rating = $('#rate').val()
        items.push(createItem(titleValue, description, rating))

        let item = [...items]
        $('.bookmark-head-list').html(mapItems(item))

        console.log(titleValue)
        render()
    })
}

function getIdOfItem(current) {
    return $(current)
        .closest('.bookmark-drop-downs')
        .data('item-id')
}


function findById(id) {

    return items.find(currentItem => currentItem.id === id)

}


function toggleFindAndHidden(id) {

    let current = findById(id)
    console.log(current)
    current.hidden = !current.hidden

}

function handleToggleHidden(){
    console.log('ran handleToggleHidden')
    $('.bookmark-head-list').on('click', 'li', function(e){
        let getId = getIdOfItem(e.target)
        console.log(getId)
        toggleFindAndHidden(getId)
        console.log(items)
        render()
    })

}
console.log(items)

function displayHTML() {
    $('#add-form').html(dropDownForm())
}

function mapItems(i) {
    let item = i.map(item => bookmarkTemplate(item))
    return item.join('')

}

function render() {
    handleToggleHidden()
    handleAddItem()
    displayHTML()

}

$(render)
```

```css
form {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 font-size: 30px;
}



.hidden {
    display: none;
}


/* inside of rating add a star value for rating*/
/* stop forgetting about content: */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bookmark App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/src/styles.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Bookmark App</h1>

    <div id='add-form'>

    </div>

    <ul class='bookmark-head-list'>

        <!-- This will have the bookmark heads -->

    </ul>

    <script src='index.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: for remove and add class: `$("#elementId").toggleClass("class");`
for hide/display element: `$("#elementId").toggle();`

Please let me know if helps so that I can answer :)

Comment: After playing around with parents and children I found the right spot. Thank You, also I found the other problem which is for some reason my render() calls keep resetting my code for some reason.